# Explanation for $M{\ddot{r}}=-\nabla \phi$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, conventions

Could someone please explain this equation $$M\bf {\ddot{r}}=-\nabla \phi$$
Where $\bf r$ is a position vector and $\phi$ is the potential function.
Could someone brief explain the potential function and tell me why we've got **minus sign** before the nabla operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minus sign is only there by convention.  You could replace $\phi$ with $-\phi$ and the minus sign would go away.  Note that $\nabla \phi$ points in the direction of steepest *ascent* for $\phi$, whereas $-\nabla \phi$ points in the direction of steepest *descent*.  Perhaps it seems nice for the force on an object to be pointing in a direction of descent for $\phi$, as if the object is trying to move to a location where $\phi$ is as small as possible.

It's simply a mathematical fact that if a vector field $F$ is conservative, then there exists a scalar-valued function $\phi$ such that $-\nabla \phi = F$.  If $F$ is a force field that some object is moving in, then we also have $F = Ma$, which yields your equation
\begin{equation*}
M {\ddot r} = -\nabla \phi.
\end{equation*}

Assuming that a vector field $F$ is conservative, how do we show mathematically the existence of $\phi$?  You can do it by first selecting some reference point $x_0$ arbitrarily, then defining
\begin{equation}
\phi(x) = -\int_{x_0}^x F \cdot dr.
\end{equation}
This line integral is taken along *any* path connecting $x_0$ to $x$.  You get the same answer no matter which path you take, because $F$ is conservative.

Then note that
\begin{align}
\phi(x + \Delta x) - \phi(x) &= -\int_x^{x + \Delta x} F(r) \cdot dr \\
&\approx -\int_x^{x + \Delta x} F(x) \cdot dr \\
&= \langle -F(x), \Delta x \rangle.
\end{align}
The approximation is good when $\Delta x$ is small.
Comparing this with the equation
\begin{equation}
\phi(x + \Delta x) - \phi(x) \approx \langle \nabla \phi(x), \Delta x \rangle
\end{equation}
shows that $\nabla \phi(x) = - F(x)$, or in other words
\begin{equation*}
-\nabla \phi(x) = F(x).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Maybe it would be good to make even more explicit, that the minus sign makes objects travel to the **minimum** of the potential, allowing us to gauge the motion of a test mass by eye from our everyday experience that things fall to the floor.

Answer (score 2):

It's total convention.  The idea is that one can caluclate, for any path:

$$\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}\right) = \int_{\rm path}{\vec F}\cdot d{\vec s}$$

One can then split the left hand side into a conservative bit and a nonconservative bit.  (with the definition of conservative being ${\vec \nabla}\times{\vec F} = 0$).  Then, since we know that any curlless vector $V$ can be expressed as ${\vec \nabla}f$ for some function $f$, we choose $f = -\phi$, and then the above expression becomes

$$\begin{align}\Delta {\rm KE} &= -\Delta \phi + \int_{\rm path}{\vec F_{\rm noncon}}\cdot d{\vec s}\\
\Delta {\rm KE} + \Delta \phi &= \int_{\rm path}{\vec F_{\rm noncon}}\cdot d{\vec s}
\end{align}$$

So, we can identify $\phi$ with the potential energy, and we see that ${\vec F} = -{\vec \nabla}\phi$

We choose the minus sign just to make the energy conservation equation look prettier, really.